# Laravel отображение картинок из public/storage

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Не отображается картинка из storage. 
Сделал линк в public папку с помощью команды `php artisan storage:link`
и загрузил туда картинку. Картинка не отображается в шаблоне.

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset('/storage/123.jpeg')}}" alt="Card">
```

При копировании картинки просто в папку public та же самая картинка отображается корректно:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{URL::asset('/123.jpeg')}}" alt="Card">
```

Почему я не могу получить доступ к картинке в /public/storage?

Comment: `{{Storage::disk('local')->url('123.jpeg')}}`

Comment: `<img class="card-img-top" src="https://localhost/storage/123.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">` ссылка все равно не работает, картинка не отображается

Comment: Проект развернут на docker-контейнерах, возможно проблема в конфигурациии...

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary
вот советую использовать уже готовую библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Забыл указать в вопросе что использую docker. Так как laravel-проект крутится на docker-контейнерах надо создавать ссылку на storage из-под контейнера, то есть:

1. Заходим в контейнер веб-сервера

   docker exec -it <имя_контейнера>
       /bin/bash
2. Тут создаем ссылку используя полные пути

   ln -s /var/www/html/storage/app/public /var/www/html/public/storage

И все работает, но ссылка за пределами docker-контейнера определяется как битая. Спасибо всем ответившим.

Answer (score 1):

Генерируйте ссылку следующим образом...в соответствии с документацией
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset

```
$url = asset('storage/123.jpeg');
```

или https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#retrieving-files

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;   


$url = Storage::url('storage/123.jpg');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem - $url = Storage::url('file.jpg');

Comment: Генерирую по документации, однако доступ к картинке почему то закрыт. Я уже все испробовал... Результат: <img class="card-img-top" src="/storage/123.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">. Ссылка есть, но не отображается.

Answer (score 0):

> Картинка должна лежать в storage/public

Для получения ссылки на изображение используйте

```
{{ asset('storage/image.jpg') }}
```

Если не сработает - проверьте работоспособность ссылки. Например, при клонировании из репозитория, ссылка превращается в пустую папку

Comment: <img class="card-img-top" src="https://localhost/storage/123.jpeg" alt="Card image cap"> все то же самое. ссылка есть, однако не отображается

Answer (score 0):

в filesystems.php для 'public' измените
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage'
на
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public/storage'

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).